# Clarification on preg_match() | Will preg_match() accept data from SQL Query result?

Tags: php, html, xampp, sqlsrv

I have a question regarding preg_match(), does it accept string from a query?

Does this work?

`$founder = $founder['idno'];` -> ex. $founder has a string value of AAA111

Will this work like this?

Supposing `$founder['idno']` = AAA111

```
<?php 
$founder = $founder['idno'];
preg_match("/(\\d+)([a-zA-Z]+)/", $founder, $result);
print($result[1]);
print($result[2]); ?>
```

It's showing an error

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\address\to\file\founder_data_modal.php on line 12

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\address\to\file\founder_data_modal.php on line 13

Comment: It would work if `$founder['idno'] = '111AAA';` or your pattern `"/([a-zA-Z]+)(\\d+)/"`. But as it is, no matches will be found.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware ````$founder['idno']```` has a string value from a query of 111AAA. Will it work?

Comment: Just try it out.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I edited my post. It's showing an error.

Comment: That's because your code doesn't return a match. Please pay attention: `'AAA111'` is not the same as `'111AAA'`. The latter will return a match.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware oh, I get it. Thank you! it should be ````"/([a-zA-Z]+)(\\d+)/"````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because there are no matches, your value doesn't match the pattern.

If the pattern is correct, check the $result variable before operating on it

```
if ($result) {
    var_dump($result);
    ... do something
} else {
    echo "No matches";
}
```

Or you can try to use different pattern that actually works for your data,
for example if you want to check if the value contains only numbers and letters you can use this pattern:

```
A-Za-z0-9]+
```

Comment: I think I got it, It should be ````/([a-zA-Z]+)(\\d+)/```` rather than ````/(\\d+)([a-zA-Z]+)/```` since the letters comes first before the numbers.